# How to solve this build.gradle Dependency in android studio?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

> Error:(5, 0) Could not find method maven() for arguments
>   [build_aag8zq3tvuj38fvgbhe3t9mrr$_run_closure1$_closure2$_closure4@767e190a] on object of type
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.DefaultMavenArtifactRepository.

[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is no `maven()` method in the app `build.gradle` and it shouldn't be. Such types of errors are most often thrown when you have edited *wrongly* the project `build.gradle`, the one not shown on your image. Without having looked at it, I couldn't be more specific.

For reference, your project `build.gradle` should look like, nothing fancy:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Comment: after implementing the above I am having an error:(5,0) could not find method maven() for arguments.... now what sholud i do ??

Comment: I put it there only for reference, meaning not copy and pasting it, rather seeing what might be wrong with yours. Could you update your question with the contents of your project `build.grade`?